# implementing the interface

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, interface

```
public interface IBSTNode
    {
        IBSTNode Left { get; }
        IBSTNode Right { get; }
        int Value { get; }        
        IDictionary<string, object> DataFields { get; set; }
        void Insert(IBSTNode node);
        string Print();   }
```

this is the interface design that I have to use. BUT I have to have the Print() function to be implemented in a way that it can take user input like

Pre-order
Post-order

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you're asking. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: You can't without going outside (or changing) the interface. Does that matter?

Comment: I cannot change Interface. That's the first condition. Second condition: can not change the signature of Print().

Answer (score 1):

so, have print take a parameter, perhaps an enum:

```
enum PrintMethod {Inorder, Postorder};
```

and

```
string Print(PrintMethod p);
```

If you cannot change the interface, you could do the unthinkable, and have Print read from stdin... *shudder *

Comment: Well, {string Print(PrintMethod p);} changes the signature of print() which is not allowed. Remember?

Answer (score 0):

The print function in the interface is paramterless it however does not limit you from adding functions that are not in the interface to the concrete class.  An interface assures a caller that a specified set of functionality is provided not that there cannot be more functionality.

Comment: I am on the same page and as I said in the comment below an overload like print(string sortorder) would be the easiest way out. But I was thinking if there would be any out of the box solution to it? something using Generic?

Answer (score 0):

Without having the user specifically know about your class, you can't do it with that interface. `IBSTNode` doesn't provide a `Print` method with arguments, so there's no way to pass the information via the call.

If they're specifically working with an instance of your class (as opposed to just an instance of some `IBSTNode`), you can define an additional method which takes these extra arguments (but you still need to implement the parameterless `Print()` method as well, due to the interface).

If absolutely necessary, you can also hack it and define a static variable somewhere (either in your own class, or perhaps in some new `PrintOptions` class) which they can set before calling `Print()` - your method can then read this variable and act accordingly. This option should be considered the absolute last resort, however.

Of course, this is assuming `Print` is supposed to be doing the traversal in the first place - that is, calling `Print` on a node will print out the children as well. A much better choice would be to move the traversal out of the IBSTNode, and only having `Print` print the individual node - and it is entirely likely that this is indeed how `Print` is supposed to work.

Since you have full access to the internals of an IBSTNode, you can write any kind of traversal you wish (assuming one isn't already defined), and if `Print` isn't just supposed to print the value of the individual node, you can even print `Value` on your own as part of that traversal.

Comment: Well, I have full privilege to implement it howwver. I just cannot change itsleft. Defining other overloads is the easiest option available something like: Print(string SortOrder). But I am thinking if there can be a way outwithout using the overload

Comment: If `Print()` is expected to do the traversal itself, rather than just print the single node value, then there's no way other than an overload or some static variable. See my updated post for more.

Answer (score 0):

You could *extend* the interface with extension methods.

If it is possible to implement the print methods as a helper method that operates on the `IBSTNode` instance via it's interface, then you could add additional print methods as extension methods.

This means the methods could be called directly on the node object when referenced as a `IBSTNode`, rather than forcing you to cast to a concrete type with overloads defined.

```
public static class IBSTNodeExtensions
{
    public static string PrintPreOrder(this IBSTNode node)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static string PrintPreOrder(this IBSTNode node)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Above I've shown two extension methods, but you could have a single one that took a parameter.